# Delphi: calculate Rect height needed for a wordwrapped text

Tags: delphi, rect

Delphi Rio 10.3.1 + GR32 (TextoutW + DT_WORDBREAK)

I want to draw text on a TBitmap32 using TextoutW from GR32's library, and I want to calculate the necessary height to accommodate wordwrapped text given a MaxWidth parameter and a specific font.

How can I calculate the necessary Rect for this?

Comment: I guess it depends on the GDI backend that you use. With `TGDIBackend.TextoutW` a call is made to the Winapi function `DrawTextW` which does offer support for calculating output rect. However, the interface to `TGDIBackend.TextoutW` passes the rect by value rather than as a var parameter. In order to deal with this you will need to call the Winapi function `DrawTextW` directly.

Comment: I'm getting always 0 returned, what am I doing wrong? "DrawTextW(bTray.Handle, PChar(OriginalTitle), Length(OriginalTitle), r, DT_CALCRECT or DT_LEFT or DT_TOP or DT_WORDBREAK);"

Comment: What is the value of `bTray.Handle`?

Comment: I was using a Form's handle, my bad, I had to use the canvas.handle (DC). But now, how do I translate the Logical Units into actual pixels?

Comment: Hang on. Aren't you drawing on a GR32 surface?

Comment: on a TBitmap32, which I then pass onto a TBitmap which is then loaded to a TImage on a form

Comment: Sounds like one step too many. You can surely draw direct from the GR32 object to your image control. Or do it in a paintbox or even the form's OnPaint. Anyway, I'm not sure what you even mean by logical coordinates. You didn't say anything about any coordinate space mapping.

Comment: From MSDN (DrawTextW) "If the function succeeds, the return value is the height of the text in logical units. "

Comment: That's fine, you can use it if you didn't apply any transformation to the device context, e.g. map mode is MM_TEXT.

Comment: Thanks, got it working. Post an answer with DrawTextW to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextoutW` method from GR32, at least for the VCL backend, wraps the Windows `DrawTextW` function. This Windows API function does provide a method to calculate the output rect via the `DT_CALCRECT` flag. However, the GR32 interface does not return the calculated rect to the caller.

So instead I suspect that you need to call `DrawTextW` directly, passing the appropriate flags and the device context (HDC) of the GR32 surface.